# Can't install some node modules

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Im trying to install some node modules I need for my script but I'm getting the following error log. Can someone explain it to me what am I doing wrong?

> npm ERR! file C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd npm ERR! path C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Git\cmd npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno ENOENT npm
>   ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd npm ERR!
>   deasync@0.1.9 install: `node ./build.js` npm ERR! spawn C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Git\cmd ENOENT npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   deasync@0.1.9 install script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem
>   with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Marija\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-06-29T12_55_19_638Z-debug.log

Comment: Your 'key' string with explanation is upper, than you've copied.

Comment: Just copy the string with command 'npm install' and the next 2-3 after it.

Comment: what string? :)

Comment: the one where you run `npm install` and next 5 after it.

Comment: Do you want to see what module I am trying to install? Its `npm install phantomjs`